# Two libs at once

Tags: python

Hey guys I am trying to make something like a keylogger I am currently using the pynput library but the problem is the program always executes the last thing I have imported for example if I import mouse listener first it doesn't catch the keyboard or the other way around so is there a way I can use both libraries at the same time?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput.mouse import Listener


def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))

def on_move(x, y):
    print('Pointer moved to {0}'.format(
        (x, y)))

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format(
        'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
        (x, y)))

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Scrolled {0}'.format(
        (x, y))),

# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll, on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing the name `Listener` twice. The second time, it will overwrite the previous Listener. I suggest doing something like:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as KeyboardListener
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.mouse import Listener as MouseListener
```

You will have to use `MouseListener` and `KeyboardListener` to refer to them.

Comment: It is still only executing Mouse listener because it is over Keyboard

Comment: @ThomasArifBaşoğlu It shouldn't be. What do you mean by executing. Do you mean defining?

Comment: No running them at the same time

Comment: `with MouseListener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll, on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:                                                                                                    
    listener.join()`

`with KeyboardListener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as klistener:
    klistener.join()`

Comment: I want to make them run at the same time @Qwerty

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can import things like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener as keyListener
from pynput.mouse import Listener as mouseListener
```

When you need to use `Listener` from the mouse library, just use `mouseListner` instead and when you need to use `Listener` from the keyboard library, just use `keyListner` instead.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput.mouse import Listener
```

The second line overwrites the name `Listener` in the global name space. One way to fix this is

```
from pynput import keyboard, mouse
```

Now you have to refer to `keyboard.Listener` or `mouse.Listener`. You will also need to do `keyboard.Key` instead of just `Key`.